# Good implementation of weak dictionary in .Net

Tags: .net, dictionary, weak-references

Where can I find good implementation of `IDictionary` which uses weak references inside?

Dictionary should be holding only weak references to values and eventually clean up itself of dead references.

Or should I just write it myself?

Comment: I think if you just use the WeakReference as value inside the dictionary that you'll have exactly what you need. See also this link, which does exactly the same to build a cache http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicholg/archive/2006/06/04/617466.aspx

Comment: Although it's not an `IDictionary`, the [ConditionalWeakTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx) is what I was really looking for when Google brought me here. Thanks to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764556/best-time-to-cull-weakreferences-in-a-collection-in-net/5764855#5764855).

Comment: It's only for .NET 4.0 though.

Comment: I have to say, the ConditionalWeakTable is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[ConditionalWeakTable Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx) uses weak keys and automatically removes the key/value entry as soon as no other references to a key exist outside the table.

Comment: It should be noted that this class uses `ReferenceEquals` rather than  `GetHashCode` and `Equals` to do equality checks. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8441180/167251 for a more thorough discussion.

Comment: The OP is asking for a weak dictionary with weak **values**. The .NET `ConditionalWeakTable` class is a weak dictionary with weak **keys**. Therefore, I do not believe this is a correct answer.

Comment: But that is what I am exactly looking for :P so thanks for confirming this!

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to write it yourself. It should be relatively straight forward, implementing the `IDictionary<T,T>` interface and then storing the actual values as `WeakReferences<T>`. You can then check the values on add/select using `TryGetTarget` to see if they're still alive.

```
public class WeakDictionary <TKey,TValue> : IDictionary<TKey,TValue>
    where TValue : class
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey,WeakReference<TValue>> innerDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey,WeakReference<TValue>>();
    
    
    public TValue Index[ TKey key ]
    {
        get
        {
            // Use .TryGetTarget instead of .IsAlive and .Target
            if (this.innerDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out WeakReference<TValue> wf) && wf.TryGetTarget(out TValue value))
            {
                return value;
            }

            return null;
        }
        
    }
    
    private void Cull()
    {
        var deadKeys = this.innerDictionary.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.IsAlive).Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();

        foreach (var key in deadKeys)
        {
            _ = this.innerDictionary.TryRemove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be wary that garbage collection can occur between `reference.IsAlive` and `reference.Target`, thus making this solution prone to race conditions.

Comment: It's easy enough to put Target on your own stack before checking IsAlive which fixes that race

Comment: Why aren't you using WeakReference.TryGetValue?

Comment: yes, like the others suggest, use TryGetTarget and WeakReference<T>

Answer (score 4):

One problem with simply holding a dictionary of WeakReference objects is that there's no way, short of enumerating the entire dictionary, of removing from the Dictionary any WeakReference objects whose targets go out of scope.

It would be helpful if a WeakReference could include a delegate which would be invoked when the primary target went out of scope.  As far as I know, there's no way to do that.  If you don't mind adding another field and a little code to the objects you're storing within your "weak dictionary", I'd suggest creating what I call a "Finasposer" object, whose sole field is a MethodInvoker; when disposed, the MethodInvoker should be nulled out; the finalizer should Interlocked.Exchange() the MethodInvoker to null and--if its old value was non-null--invoke it.  The object to be written in the dictionary should create a new Finasposer object, with a delegate that will cause the key to be removed from the dictionary when convenient.

Note that the neither the finalizer nor any delegate invoked thereby should never directly manipulate the dictionary, nor do anything that would require acquiring a lock.  If the Finasposer holds a delegate, that delegate itself is guaranteed to be valid when Finalize executes, but the object attached to the delegate, and any objects referenced thereby, may be in unexpected states.  It should be safe, however, for the Finasposer-called method to add to a linked list a reference to the object that went out of scope.  The Dictionary's Add, Remove, and other methods could poll the linked list to see if any of the WeakReferences therein had died and needed to be cleaned out.

Comment: There is way to have a notification after the object is collected. ConditionalWeakTable can help here. Please see my blog [WeakTable](http://www.nesterovsky-bros.com/weblog/2014/01/08/WeakTable.aspx) for details.

Comment: I just want to say, _as soon as I read the first two sentences of the second paragraph of this answer_, I knew it was supercat. (Before I scrolled down to confirm.) Signature style and tone. Stands out from every other answerer on this site that I've read in 12 years. Thoughtful and _especially_ exploratory. I've never not enjoyed a supercat answer. I don't want to make this a fan thing, I just really appreciate the answer style.

Comment: @supercat - See my answer below. I think I'm doing what you say not to do.  I can understand not doing things from the Finalizer thread - like manipulating the dictionary and taking locks, but as far as your other recommendations, I don't see the reason for those. Like, what is so special about using a MethodInvoker? Thanks.

Comment: @N73k: I don't think `ConditionalWeakTable` was available when I wrote the answer.  As for the `Finasposer` class, the basic idea was to encapsulate finalization logic in a general-purpose class which would run a specified piece of code when a particular object has ceased to exist.  Note that the Finalize method doesn't actually indicate when an object is garbage collected, but rather when an object *would have been* garbage collected in the absence of a registered `Finalize` method somewhere in the object tree.  Finding out when an object has actually been garbage collected and...

Comment: ...can be guaranteed never to be "resurrected" [which could instead be more accurately described as "given a reprieve"] is a bit tricky; using a Finasposer class would isolate the rest of the program from such trickiness.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Well I think my code will work. I actually don't see why not to modify the dictionary and take a lock from the finalizer thread. There won't be any deadlocks. I mean, as long as that reference to this.outer is not null, everything should work.

Comment: @N73k: The `ConditionalWeakTable` is designed to be thread-safe, so you should be fine.  When I wrote my answer, the available collection classes were `Dictionary` and `HashTable`, neither of which would be thread-safe without locking.

Comment: In .NET Core 2.0+ `ConditionalWeakTable` implements `IEnumerable<...>`.

Comment: @Vlad: That's interesting, though the enumeration seems underspecified.  A thread-safe collection that supports `IEnumerable<T>` should document what is or is not guaranteed about enumeration, including the order in which items are returned and how that would interact with actions by other threads; a collection that interacts with the GC should document what items will be kept alive during enumeration.  Unfortunately, I don't see anything about those behavioral aspects in the description of `ConditionalWeakTable`.

Comment: @supercat: I suppose you can submit an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/docs

Comment: @supercat: As I understand the documentation, only the current item is kept alive. But of course more formal guarantees would be good. E. g. is the list of entries snapshotted at `GetEnumerator`?

Answer (score 4):

This will work without the performance problems of the other solutions.

(It doesn't rely on a "shrink" method being called upon every request in order to manually get rid of dead objects. And these "shrink" methods would have to loop through every item on every call. I do have a "shrink" method, but it is only called when the items would be enumerated anyway.)

The key to the problem is to use a "holder" object as a value in the ConditionalWeakTable, so that when the key gets dropped, the holder's finalizer will trigger, which removes the key from the "active list" of keys.

I tested this and it works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Util
{
    public class WeakDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IDisposable
        where TKey : class
        where TValue : class
    {
        private readonly object locker = new object();
        //private readonly HashSet<WeakReference> weakKeySet = new HashSet<WeakReference>(new ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer<WeakReference>());
        private ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, WeakKeyHolder> keyHolderMap = new ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, WeakKeyHolder>();
        private Dictionary<WeakReference, TValue> valueMap = new Dictionary<WeakReference, TValue>(new ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer<WeakReference>());


        private class WeakKeyHolder
        {
            private WeakDictionary<TKey, TValue> outer;
            private WeakReference keyRef;

            public WeakKeyHolder(WeakDictionary<TKey, TValue> outer, TKey key)
            {
                this.outer = outer;
                this.WeakRef = new WeakReference(key);
            }

            public WeakReference WeakRef { get; private set; }

            ~WeakKeyHolder()
            {
                this.outer?.onKeyDrop(this.WeakRef);  // Nullable operator used just in case this.outer gets set to null by GC before this finalizer runs. But I haven't had this happen.
            }
        }

        private void onKeyDrop(WeakReference weakKeyRef)
        {
            lock(this.locker)
            {
                if (!this.bAlive)
                    return;

                //this.weakKeySet.Remove(weakKeyRef);
                this.valueMap.Remove(weakKeyRef);
            }
        }

        
    // The reason for this is in case (for some reason which I have never seen) the finalizer trigger doesn't work
    // There is not much performance penalty with this, since this is only called in cases when we would be enumerating the inner collections anyway.
        private void manualShrink()
        {
            var keysToRemove = this.valueMap.Keys.Where(k => !k.IsAlive).ToList();

            foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
                valueMap.Remove(key);
        }

        private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> currentDictionary
        {
            get
            {
                lock(this.locker)
                {
                    this.manualShrink();
                    return this.valueMap.ToDictionary(p => (TKey) p.Key.Target, p => p.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        public TValue this[TKey key]
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.TryGetValue(key, out var val))
                    return val;

                throw new KeyNotFoundException();
            }

            set
            {
                this.set(key, value, isUpdateOkay: true);
            }
        }

        private bool set(TKey key, TValue val, bool isUpdateOkay)
        {
            lock (this.locker)
            {
                if (this.keyHolderMap.TryGetValue(key, out var weakKeyHolder))
                {
                    if (!isUpdateOkay)
                        return false;

                    this.valueMap[weakKeyHolder.WeakRef] = val;
                    return true;
                }

                weakKeyHolder = new WeakKeyHolder(this, key);
                this.keyHolderMap.Add(key, weakKeyHolder);
                //this.weakKeySet.Add(weakKeyHolder.WeakRef);
                this.valueMap.Add(weakKeyHolder.WeakRef, val);

                return true;
            }
        }

        public ICollection<TKey> Keys
        {
            get
            {
                lock(this.locker)
                {
                    this.manualShrink();
                    return this.valueMap.Keys.Select(k => (TKey) k.Target).ToList();
                }
            }
        }

        public ICollection<TValue> Values
        {
            get
            {
                lock (this.locker)
                {
                    this.manualShrink();
                    return this.valueMap.Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
                }
            }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                lock (this.locker)
                {
                    this.manualShrink();
                    return this.valueMap.Count;
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly => false;

        public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
        {
            if (!this.set(key, value, isUpdateOkay: false))
                throw new ArgumentException("Key already exists");
        }

        public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            this.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            lock(this.locker)
            {
                this.keyHolderMap = new ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, WeakKeyHolder>();
                this.valueMap.Clear();
            }
        }

        public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            WeakKeyHolder weakKeyHolder = null;
            object curVal = null;

            lock (this.locker)
            {
                if (!this.keyHolderMap.TryGetValue(item.Key, out weakKeyHolder))
                    return false;

                curVal = weakKeyHolder.WeakRef.Target;
            }

            return (curVal?.Equals(item.Value) == true);
        }

        public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
        {
            lock (this.locker)
            {
                return this.keyHolderMap.TryGetValue(key, out var weakKeyHolder);
            }
        }

        public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>) this.currentDictionary).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.currentDictionary.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public bool Remove(TKey key)
        {
            lock (this.locker)
            {
                if (!this.keyHolderMap.TryGetValue(key, out var weakKeyHolder))
                    return false;

                this.keyHolderMap.Remove(key);
                this.valueMap.Remove(weakKeyHolder.WeakRef);

                return true;
            }
        }

        public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            lock (this.locker)
            {
                if (!this.keyHolderMap.TryGetValue(item.Key, out var weakKeyHolder))
                    return false;

                if (weakKeyHolder.WeakRef.Target?.Equals(item.Value) != true)
                    return false;

                this.keyHolderMap.Remove(item.Key);
                this.valueMap.Remove(weakKeyHolder.WeakRef);

                return true;
            }
        }

        public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
        {
            lock (this.locker)
            {
                if (!this.keyHolderMap.TryGetValue(key, out var weakKeyHolder))
                {
                    value = default(TValue);
                    return false;
                }
                
                value = this.valueMap[weakKeyHolder.WeakRef];
                return true;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }

        private bool bAlive = true;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
        }

        protected void Dispose(bool bManual)
        {
            if (bManual)
            {
                Monitor.Enter(this.locker);

                if (!this.bAlive)
                    return;
            }
            
            try
            {
                this.keyHolderMap = null;
                this.valueMap = null;
                this.bAlive = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (bManual)
                    Monitor.Exit(this.locker);
            }
        }

        ~WeakDictionary()
        {
            this.Dispose(false);
        }
    }


public class ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public static ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer<T> Default = new ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer<T>();

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj);
    }
}

public class ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer : ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer<object>
{
}

}
```

Comment: Surprised this doesn't have more upvotes! Very clever. Only one drawback is the keys have to be classes.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that all existing answers either:

- implement a dictionary with weak references to the *keys* as opposed to the *values*, or
- rely on an explicit "purge" operation that needs to be called from time to time in order to clean up old references

I've implemented a version that applies weak references to the dictionary *values*, removing the entries of garbage collected values immediately.

**Repo:** [bhaeussermann/weak-dictionary](https://github.com/bhaeussermann/weak-dictionary)

**NuGet package:** [BernhardHaus.Collections.WeakDictionary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BernhardHaus.Collections.WeakDictionary)

**Article:** [Creating a weak dictionary in .NET](https://dev.to/bhaeussermann/creating-a-weak-dictionary-in-net-1fo)

Implementation notes:

- The `ConditionalWeakTable` class holds a weak reference to its *key*, but we want the weak reference to be on the *value*. Therefore we use our dictionary's values as the keys of the `ConditionalWeakTable`.
- When the key gets garbage collected, `ConditionalWeakTable` removes the relevant entry and this causes the *value* to be garbage collected as well (assuming there are no other references to the value). This causes the deconstructor of the value object to be invoked. We leverage this in order to immediately remove the corresponding entry from the internal dictionary.

```
public class WeakDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    where TValue : class
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, WeakReference> internalDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, WeakReference>();
    private readonly ConditionalWeakTable<TValue, Finalizer> conditionalWeakTable = new ConditionalWeakTable<TValue, Finalizer>();

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get => (TValue)internalDictionary[key].Target;
        set
        {
            Remove(key);
            Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys => internalDictionary.Keys;

    public ICollection<TValue> Values => internalDictionary.Values.Select(r => (TValue)r.Target).ToArray();

    public int Count => internalDictionary.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        internalDictionary.Add(key, new WeakReference(value));
        var finalizer = new Finalizer(key);
        finalizer.ValueFinalized += k => Remove(k);
        conditionalWeakTable.Add(value, finalizer);
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) => Add(item.Key, item.Value);

    // Implement the remaining IDictionary<,> methods to simply relay the method call to internalDictionary.
    // See https://github.com/bhaeussermann/weak-dictionary/blob/main/src/WeakDictionary/WeakDictionary.cs for the complete implementation.
    // ...

    private sealed class Finalizer
    {
        private readonly TKey valueKey;

        public Finalizer(TKey valueKey)
        {
            this.valueKey = valueKey;
        }

        ~Finalizer()
        {
            ValueFinalized?.Invoke(valueKey);
        }

        public event ValueFinalizedDelegate ValueFinalized;
    }

    private delegate void ValueFinalizedDelegate(TKey valueKey);
}
```

Here's an NUnit test that shows that an entry is removed once its value no longer has any references to it.

This has been tested on both .NET Framework and .NET Core. Note that in order to see it work with .NET Core compiler optimizations need to be switched on, and the debugger must not be attached. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68836653/359765).

```
[Test]
public void WeakDictionary()
{
    var v1 = new ValueType();
    var v2 = new ValueType();
    var v3 = new ValueType();

    var dictionary = new WeakDictionary<int, ValueType>
    {
        { 1, v1 },
        { 2, v2 },
        { 3, v3 }
    };

    var weakReference = new WeakReference(v2);
    v2 = null;

    // Loop forces non-referenced values to be garbage collected on .NET Core (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68836653/359765)
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }

    Assert.IsFalse(weakReference.IsAlive);
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new int[] { 1, 3 }, dictionary.Keys, "Unexpected keys after garbage collection.");

    // These references to v1 and v2 prevent the compiler from adding optimizations that will cause v1 and v2 to be garbage collected.
    v1.ToString();
    v3.ToString();
}

private class ValueType { }
```

Comment: This answer would be much improved if the WeakDictionary class compiled clean.  Some of the methods not implemented such as CopyTo are private and cannot be implemented easily with 'simply relay the method call to internalDictionary' as suggested in the source.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I added a link to the file in the GitHub repo. The code is also available as a NuGet package, which I added to the answer as well.

Comment: With regards to CopyTo, the C# language allows subclasses that implement public interface methods to reduce the visibility of those implementations to private, which seems completely pointless, especially when a cast of the implementing class back to the inteface type can get around the same reduction of visibility to make the method public again.  What is code like this doing in the .net framework itself?

Comment: @busitech I had a look.

Dictionary<T, U> implements both ICollection<KeyValuePair<T, U>> and ICollection. Both have a CopyTo() method, and because of this it needs to implement both as ICollection<KeyValuePair<T, U>>.CopyTo() and ICollection.CopyTo() respectively (it happens to declare a private CopyTo() method as well).

The way it declares these two CopyTo() methods, associating each with its corresponding interface, means that in order to call the method you need to cast the dictionary reference to the correct interface type in order to disambiguate which CopyTo() method to call.

Comment: I'm wondering if you feel this still begs the original question, about whether this kind of code belongs in the .net framework, from a design standpoint.  In your opinion, would the framework or language developers have done the community a favor by using a cleaner design? One would assume that reusing identical method names in the generic and non-generic interfaces was done to add simplicity, yet here we are, still dealing with the complexity of multiple layers of overlapping names and duplicative interfaces in a single class, to the point of being unable to use the class easily...  : )

Comment: I'm not sure what such a "cleaner design" would look like. I guess it would have been possible to avoid the interfaces having overlapping method names. However, assuming that "CopyTo" was the ideal method name for both interfaces independently, this would have meant choosing sub-optimal names. Further, any code that deals with say an ICollection-typed object should be able to use a method called "CopyTo" and be oblivious about the fact that there happens to be a different interface having a method with the same name.

Comment: I think it's also worthwhile to note that the IDictionary<T, U> interface extends only the generically-typed ICollection<KeyValuePair<T, U>>. This means that in any code that works with a reference of type IDictonary<T, U>, the method-name ambiguity does not exist, as you will automatically be calling the CopyTo() method of the ICollection<KeyValuePair<T, U>> type. This serves as a motivation to reference the interface type IDictionary<T, U> as opposed to the class type Dictionary<T, U>, which is a better programming practice anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is my version of a concurrent weak (value) dictionary:

```
public class WeakConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue> where TValue : class
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, WeakReference<TValue>> _internalDictionary =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, WeakReference<TValue>>();

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (_internalDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var weakReference) &&
                weakReference.TryGetTarget(out var value))
                return value;

            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            _internalDictionary.TryAdd(key, new WeakReference<TValue>(value));
        }
    }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys => _internalDictionary.Keys;

    public ICollection<TValue> Values => _internalDictionary.Values
        .Select(_ => _.GetTarget())
        .Where(_ => _ != null)
        .ToList();

    public int Count => _internalDictionary.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Purge();
        if (!_internalDictionary.TryAdd(key, new WeakReference<TValue>(value)))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Key already existing");
        }
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _internalDictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) => _internalDictionary.TryGetValue(item.Key, out var weakReference) &&
                weakReference.GetTarget() == item.Value;

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) => _internalDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var weakReference) &&
                weakReference.IsAlive();

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        Purge();
        _internalDictionary
            .Select(_ => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(_.Key, _.Value.GetTarget()))
            .Where(_ => _.Value != null)
            .ToList()
            .CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Purge();
        return _internalDictionary
            .Select(_ => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(_.Key, _.Value.GetTarget()))
            .Where(_ => _.Value != null)
            .GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        return _internalDictionary.TryRemove(key, out var weakReference);
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        value = null;
        if (_internalDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var weakReference))
        {
            value = weakReference.GetTarget();
        }

        return value != null;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        Purge();
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Purge()
    {
        foreach (var itemToRemove in _internalDictionary
            .Select(_ => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(_.Key, _.Value.GetTarget()))
            .Where(_ => _.Value == null))
        {
            _internalDictionary.TryRemove(itemToRemove.Key, out var weakReference);
        }
    }
}

public static class WeakReferenceExtensions
{
    public static bool IsAlive<T>([NotNull] this WeakReference<T> weakReference) where T : class =>
        weakReference.TryGetTarget(out var target);

    public static T GetTarget<T>([NotNull] this WeakReference<T> weakReference, T defaultValue = default(T)) where T : class
    {
        if (!weakReference.TryGetTarget(out T target))
            return defaultValue;

        return target;
    }
}
```

and a test proving that reference to value is actually discarded:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestWeakDictionary()
    {
        var weakDict = new WeakConcurrentDictionary<string, TestItem>();

        {
            var testItem = new TestItem();
            weakDict.Add("testitem", testItem);

            Assert.AreEqual(1, weakDict.Count);
            Assert.AreSame(testItem, weakDict["testitem"]);
        }

        GC.Collect();
        Assert.IsNull(weakDict["testitem"]);
        weakDict.Purge();
        Assert.AreEqual(0, weakDict.Count);
    }
```

Some notes:

1. Property Keys returns all keys even of those entries whose value has been collected, but Values always returns live not-null objects.
2. this[key] CAN return null
3. You can optionally call Purge to clear entries whose values have been collected
4. Test works when compiled and executed in Release mode

Answer (score 1):

It is one thing to have WeakReferences to values, but I found that Dictionary keys can also be a source of memory leaks.  Here is a bare bones implementation with WeakReference to keys:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Common.library.collections {

    /// <summary>
    /// THIS DICTIONARY WILL NOT "HANG ON" TO THE KEYS IT USES
    /// IF THE KEY IS GARBAGE COLLECTED, THE VALUE WILL BE RELEASED TOO
    /// </summary>
    public class Dictionary_usingWeakKey<K, V> {
        //MAP FROM HASH CODE TO LIST OF KEY/VALUE PAIRS
        private Dictionary<int, List<Pair>> dic = new Dictionary<int, List<Pair>>();


        public void Add(K key, V value) {
            if (value==null){
                this.Remove(key);
                return;
            }//endif

            List<Pair> list = null;
            dic.TryGetValue(key.GetHashCode(), out list);
            if (list == null) {
                list = new List<Pair>();
                dic.Add(key.GetHashCode(), list);
            }//endif

            Boolean isDirty = false;            
            foreach(Pair p in list){
                if (p.Key.Target == null) {
                    isDirty = true;
                    continue;
                }//endif
                if (p.Key.Target == (Object)key) {
                    p.Value = (Object)value;
                    if (isDirty) cleanList(list);
                    return;
                }//endif
            }//for
            if (isDirty) cleanList(list);

            Pair newP=new Pair();
            newP.Key = new WeakReference(key);
            newP.Value = value;
            list.Add(newP);
        }//method


        public bool ContainsKey(K key) {
            List<Pair> list = null;
            dic.TryGetValue(key.GetHashCode(), out list);
            if (list == null) return false;

            Boolean isDirty = false;
            foreach (Pair p in list) {
                if (p.Key.Target == null) {
                    isDirty = true;
                    continue;
                }//endif
                if (p.Key.Target == (Object)key) {
                    if (isDirty) cleanList(list);
                    return true;
                }//endif
            }//for
            if (isDirty) cleanList(list);

            return false;
        }//method



        private void cleanList(List<Pair> list) {
            var temp = (from Pair p in list where p.Key.Target != null select p);
            list.Clear();
            list.AddRange(temp);
        }//method



        public bool Remove(K key) {
            List<Pair> list = null;
            dic.TryGetValue(key.GetHashCode(), out list);
            if (list == null) return true;

            foreach (Pair p in list) {
                if (p.Key.Target == (Object)key) {
                    p.Value = null;
                    break;
                }//endif
            }//for
            cleanList(list);

            return true;
        }//method





        public V this[K key] {
            get {
                List<Pair> list = null;
                dic.TryGetValue(key.GetHashCode(), out list);
                if (list == null) return default(V);

                Boolean isDirty = false;
                foreach (Pair p in list) {
                    if (p.Key.Target == null) {
                        isDirty = true;
                        continue;
                    }//endif

                    if (p.Key.Target == (Object)key) {
                        if (isDirty) cleanList(list);
                        return (V)p.Value;
                    }//endif
                }//for
                if (isDirty) cleanList(list);

                return default(V);
            }
            set {
                this.Add(key, value);
            }
        }


        public void Add(KeyValuePair<K, V> item) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Clear() {
            dic.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<K, V> item) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<K, V>[] array, int arrayIndex) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Count {
            get {
                throw new NotImplementedException();            
                //return dic.Count();           
            }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<K, V> item) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }



        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<K, V>> GetEnumerator() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();    
            //return dic.GetEnumerator();
        }


        //System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        //    return ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)dic).GetEnumerator();
        //}





    }//class



    public class Pair{
        public WeakReference Key;
        public Object Value;
    }//method

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If identity comparison cannot be used then ConditionalWeakTable is not an option.

In this case I dare to suggest our implementation 
[WeakTable.cs](http://nesterovsky-bros.com/download/WeakTable.cs.txt),
and our description in the blog 
[WeakTable](http://www.nesterovsky-bros.com/weblog/2014/01/08/WeakTable.aspx).