# Should ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue> be used for non-compiler purposes?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, clr, weak-references, ephemeron

I've recently come across the [`ConditionalWeakTable<TKey,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx) class in my search for an `IDictionary` which uses weak references, as suggested in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784291/good-implementation-of-weak-dictionary-in-net) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764556/best-time-to-cull-weakreferences-in-a-collection-in-net/5764855#5764855).

There is [a definitive MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2009/05/18/the-conditional-weak-table-enabling-dynamic-object-properties.aspx) which introduced the class and which states:

> You can find the class ... in the System.Runtime.CompilerServices namespace. It’s in CompilerServices because it’s not a general-purpose dictionary type: we intend for it to only be used by compiler writers.

and later again:

> ...the conditional weak table is not intended to be a general purpose collection... But if you’re writing a .NET language of your own and need to expose the ability to attach properties to objects you should definitely look into the Conditional Weak Table.

In line with this, the MSDN entry description of the class reads:

> Enables compilers to dynamically attach object fields to managed objects.

So obviously it was originally created for a very specific purpose - to help the DLR, and the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace embodies this. But it seems to have found a much wider use than that - even within the CLR. If I search for references of [ConditionalWeakTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx) in [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx), for example, I can see that is used in the MEF class [`CatalogExportProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.catalogexportprovider.aspx) and in the internal WPF `DataGridHelper` class, amongst others.

My question is whether it is okay to use [ConditionalWeakTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx) outside of compiler writing and language tools, and whether there is any risk in doing so in terms of incurring additional overhead or of the implementation changing significantly in future .NET versions. (Or should it be avoided and a custom implementation like [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicholg/archive/2006/06/04/617466.aspx) be used instead).

There is also further reading [here](http://weblog.ikvm.net/PermaLink.aspx?guid=7f47ad08-cdef-4dc2-b2fd-5dfdc1baf11d), [here](http://blog.gx.weltkante.de/2011/06/true-weak-keyed-dictionary.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441055/is-it-possible-to-create-a-truely-weak-keyed-dictionary-in-c) about how the [ConditionalWeakTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx) makes use of a hidden CLR implementation of [ephemerons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeron) (via `System.Runtime.Compiler.Services. DependentHandle`) to deal with the problem of cycles between keys and values, and how this cannot easily be accomplished in a custom manner.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with using `ConditionalWeakTable`. If you need ephemerons, you pretty much have no other choice.

I don't think future .NET versions will be a problem - even if only compilers would use this class, Microsoft still couldn't change it without breaking compatibility with existing binaries.

As for overhead - there certainly will be overhead compared to a normal Dictionary. Having many `DependentHandle`s probably will be expensive similarly to how many `WeakReference`s are more expensive than normal references (the GC has to do additional work to scan them to see if they need to be nulled out). But that's not a problem unless you have lots (several million) of entries.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark that as the answer. I think you're right - I want a Dictionary that uses weak references, so ConditionalWeakTable shouldn't introduce any more overhead compared to any other implementation that uses weak references, with the added benefit of using ephemerons.

Comment: I was really excited about the availability of ConditionalWeakTable, but I noticed this in the documentation: "You cannot control equality comparisons by overriding Object.GetHashCode to explicitly set the hash code for a key. The ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue> class does not use the Object.GetHashCode method to compute hash codes, and therefore does not invoke Object.GetHashCode overrides." - Making it not useful for my purposes. :(

Comment: @Sean: There's no way a `ConditionalWeakTable` could use anything other than reference identity for the keys, since it would be impossible (Halting Problem) for it to know when it was no longer possible for code to supply a key which should match an item in the collection.