# Would a static variable in an instance class cause a memory leak in c#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, static

I have the following class which I have simplified for this example

```
public class SearchService : ISearchService
{

    private static Dictionary<long, object> _resultCache = new Dictionary<long, object>();
   
     public SearchService()
     {
         _resultCache.Add(new Random().Next(),new Cat());
     }
}
```

This service is registered in a .net core service as

```
service.AddScoped<ISearchService,SearchService>();
```

Meaning a new service will be registered for every request

Would the static variable in the instance class cause the class not to be disposed of?

and therefore cause a memory leak

Comment: Your problem will be rather that your code tries to add an entry with the same key multiple times to the dictionary. This will result in an exception.

Comment: Not just duplicate keys, but also multi-threading since dictionaries are not thread-safe. Personally, I would switch to using a `ConcurrentDictionary`, but also instead of a static  property, inject a singleton class containing the data and methods to access it.

Comment: @JKennedy: See [Static Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members).  **_Two common uses of static fields are to keep a count of the number of objects that have been instantiated, or to store a value that must be shared among all instances._**

Comment: oh yes sorry ignore the duplicate keys issue, it was a bad example

Comment: You need to think about who is cleaning up "old" data from the dictionary.

Comment: Also, what happens if in future you decide to use a proper caching solution? This dictionary would be a bad idea, so injecting a proper service would be preferable to do now.

Comment: When the purpose of that service is to cache everything in that single instance of the dictionary why is the service not a singleton? You might want to look at the Frameworks Cache or MemoryCache classes for this instead of Dictionary. They have features like TTL's to remove old data. A typical thing for a cache.

Comment: Perhaps [`ConditionalWeakTable<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.conditionalweaktable-2?view=net-8.0) is what you need.  As an added bonus it's stated to be thread safe.  See [Good implementation of weak dictionary in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2784291). Do note that you will need to deal with dictionary key collisions.

Comment: Are you actually trying to associate your `Cat` object with your `SearchService` object, and are using the random `long` value as a lookup key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actual intent here is to associate your `Cat` object with every `SearchService` object currently allocated without preventing the garbage collection of instances of either, you can use [`ConditionalWeakTable<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.conditionalweaktable-2%60) for this:

> The `ConditionalWeakTable<TKey,TValue>` class differs from other collection objects in its management of the object lifetime of keys stored in the collection. Ordinarily, when an object is stored in a collection, its lifetime lasts until it is removed (and there are no additional references to the object) or until the collection object itself is destroyed. However, in the `ConditionalWeakTable<TKey,TValue>` class, adding a key/value pair to the table does not ensure that the key will persist, even if it can be reached directly from a value stored in the table (for example, if the table contains one key, A, with a value V1, and a second key, B, with a value P2 that contains a reference to A). Instead, **`ConditionalWeakTable<TKey,TValue>` automatically removes the key/value entry as soon as no other references to a key exist outside the table. <sup>[1]</sup>**
>
> Instances of the `ConditionalWeakTable<TKey,TValue>` class are thread safe. They do not require callers to do any additional locking.

Thus if you modify your `SearchService` as follows:

```
public class SearchService : ISearchService
{
    static ConditionalWeakTable<SearchService, object> _resultCache = new();

    public SearchService()
    {
        _resultCache.Add(this, new Cat());
    }
    
    public static bool TryGetCat(ISearchService iService, out Cat cat)
    {
        cat = null;
        return iService is SearchService service && _resultCache.TryGetValue(service, out var obj) && ((cat = obj as Cat) != null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Cat> AllCats => _resultCache.Select(p => p.Value).OfType<Cat>();
    
    public static IEnumerable<ISearchService> AllServces => _resultCache.Select(p => p.Key);
}
```

The following test will now execute successfully and demonstrate that no references to `SearchService` or `Cat` were retained after they were no longer used elsewhere:

```
static void TestSearchService()
{
    static void Setup()
    {
        ISearchService service = new SearchService();
        
        Assert.That(SearchService.TryGetCat(service, out var cat));
        Assert.That(SearchService.AllServces.Count() > 0);
        Assert.That(SearchService.AllCats.Count() > 0);
        
        GC.KeepAlive(service); // Make sure service is not collected before the above asserts complete.
    }
    
    Setup();
    
    GC.Collect();
    
    Assert.That(SearchService.AllServces.Count() == 0);
    Assert.That(SearchService.AllCats.Count() == 0);
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CgKNpc).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Some testing shows the documentation statement to be imprecise.  Instead it appears from the [unit tests for `ConditionalWeakTable`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Runtime/tests/System.Runtime.Tests/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/ConditionalWeakTableTests.cs) that it automatically removes the key/value entry as soon as no other references to the key exist outside the table other than [weak references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/weak-references) and the key gets garbage collected.  (The tests trigger this by calling `GC.Collect()` directly.)

See also the [source comments](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/ConditionalWeakTable.cs#L25-L27):

> ```
> ** Lifetimes of keys and values:
> **
> **    Inserting a key and value into the dictonary will not
> **    prevent the key from dying, even if the key is strongly reachable
> **    from the value.
> **
> **    Prior to ConditionalWeakTable, the CLR did not expose
> **    the functionality needed to implement this guarantee.
> **
> **    Once the key dies, the dictionary automatically removes
> **    the key/value entry.
> ```

Since your requirement here is to prevent memory leaks and allow garbage collection of `SearchService` and `Cat`, this is sufficient.

Comment: The bolded sentence quoted from the documentation is total malarkey.  If it were correct, you wouldn't need `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();` in the demonstration.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Hmm.  Well it's not correct but it's not total malarky either.  The correct statement seems to be *ConditionalWeakTable<TKey,TValue> automatically removes the key/value entry as soon as no other references to a key exist outside the table **and the key is garbage collected***.  Which seems to be adequate to the querent's needs, which is to prevent memory leaks.  Do you think I need to update the answer?

Comment: Still inaccurate.  You can have the same key referenced in two tables, or a table and an additional weak reference, and it will be eligible for GC.  I'm also not sure that the table entry is immediately removed or whether it happens at some time post-GC when something triggers the table to scrub its entries.

Comment: However it's not your statement that's wrong, it's the official documentation.  Probably worth mentioning at least that the rule is actually that the table won't prevent collection of the key.

Comment: Somewhat surprising (and still different from the documentation claim): https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/ConditionalWeakTable.cs#L25-L27

Comment: @BenVoigt - MSFT's own [unit tests for ConditionalWeakTable](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Runtime/tests/System.Runtime.Tests/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/ConditionalWeakTableTests.cs) seem to assume that a call to `GC.Collect();` clears the table of garbage-collected content.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely deeply integrated into the GC such that reachability of both key and value account for it being a ConditionalWeakTable.  Actually it seems that the "magic" data type is `ConditionalWeakTable.DependentHandle`.

Comment: @BenVoigt - answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

From a memory consumption perspective, you have a dictionary that grows infinitely and also retains the instances of the `Cat`. So, there will be a some sort of "leak" of such an objects. The `SearchService` instances themselves will be not leaked. You may consider to add some additional logic into `SearchService.Dispose` or in the other place in order to remove from the dictionary those `Cat` objects which are not needed anymore. As an options, you may think about moving the caching logic completely in the separate service and apply some expiration policy and other cleanup strategy or just to use some existing caching solutions.